# Moving Excel data fields to Word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to make shipping labels for my clients and I need a hand. I have over 500 customers all in an excel file with the usual (Name, Phone #, Address) data fields.

I want to create a VBA that will automatically run a loop to fill my word document with the right data from the Excel file. The word document will be small labels.

Comment: It's worth being a bit clearer on what you're expected output will look like (maybe a screenshot?). Also if you could share what you've tried so far as well as any code (edit your original question rather than add a comment)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need Mail Merge.  Check out the links below.  That should do what you want.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/08/mail-merge-excel-word/

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/print/word2013/mail-merge?playlist=Word_2013

http://www.wa.gov/esd/training/docs/quick_guides/MailMergewithExcelDataFiles.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiuh7qmA_uc